# Expander List View in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, controls, expander

I want to do the exact expander view which is available for Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

I am creating Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App (Not silverlight).

I have searched and refered some links . Some of them are for Silverlight and some of them are for Windows phone 7. But I am not getting exact solution for Windows phon 8.1 Universal App.

Any ideas suggestion would be greately appreciated...

Thanks.
Ilaiya.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try/find this port for WinRT? https://expanderview.codeplex.com/